# Terraform syntax help to include instance ids from two instances to a single array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, syntax, terraform, amazon-elb

This is how my code looks,

```
module "alb_api" {
  source = "./modules/load-balancer"
  env = "${lower(var.env)}"
  project = "api"
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.main.id}"
  public_subnet1_id = "${var.public_subnet1_id}"
  public_subnet2_id = "${var.public_subnet2_id}"
  health_check_target_group_path = "/status"
  certificate_arn = "${var.certificate_arn}"
  alb_target_group_port = "1984"
  current_ec2_instance_ids = "${aws_instance.ec2[*].id}"
  next_ec2_instance_ids = "${aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id}"
}
```

I need to be able to combine instances Ids from two instances to a single array

**Expectation**

```
ec2_instance_ids = "${aws_instance.ec2[*].id},${aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id}"
```

This give me a syntax error, Is it possible to achieve this ? what would be the proper syntax is so ?

Inside the module I'm registering these instances to a load-balancer, code below

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "alb_target_group_attachment" {
  count = length("${var.current_ec2_instance_ids}")
  target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn}"
  target_id = "${var.current_ec2_instance_ids[count.index]}"
  port = "${var.alb_target_group_port}"
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "next_alb_target_group_attachment" {
  count = length("${var.next_ec2_instance_ids}")
  target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn}"
  target_id = "${var.next_ec2_instance_ids[count.index]}"
  port = "${var.alb_target_group_port}"
}
```

I need to combine these to a single as well

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "alb_target_group_attachment" {
  count = length("${var.ec2_instance_ids}")
  target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn}"
  target_id = "${var.ec2_instance_ids[count.index]}"
  port = "${var.alb_target_group_port}"
}
```

**Current version of code**

```
module "alb_example-backend" {
  source = "./modules/load-balancer"
  env = "${lower(var.env)}"
  project = "example-backend"
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.main.id}"
  public_subnet1_id = "${var.public_subnet1_id}"
  public_subnet2_id = "${var.public_subnet2_id}"
  health_check_target_group_path ="/status"
  certificate_arn = "${var.certificate_arn}"
  alb_target_group_port = "2010"
  ec2_instance_ids = concat(aws_instance.ec2[*].id,aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id)
}
```

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "alb_target_group_attachment" {
  count = length("${var.ec2_instance_ids}")
  target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn}"
  target_id = "${var.ec2_instance_ids[count.index]}"
  port = "${var.alb_target_group_port}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To join two lists, `aws_instance.ec2[*].id` and `aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id` you can use [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html). Since your syntax is for 0.11, then it would be:

```
ec2_instance_ids = "${concat(aws_instance.ec2.*.id, aws_instance.next_ec2.*.id)}"
```

For TF 0.12+:

```
ec2_instance_ids = concat(aws_instance.ec2[*].id, aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id)
```

Comment: awesome I will try this out, Thanks heaps!

Comment: @MahelaWickramasekara No problem. Let me know how it will go.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm checking the length from the module

#######################

Error: Invalid count argument

  on provisioners/different-box/modules/load-balancer/resources.tf line 107, in resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "alb_target_group_attachment":
 107:   count = length("${var.ec2_instance_ids}")
##########################################

Comment: @MahelaWickramasekara Which version of TF are you using?

Comment: ✗ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.10
+ provider.aws v2.68.0

Comment: I used concat like this,
ec2_instance_ids = concat(aws_instance.ec2[*].id,aws_instance.next_ec2[*].id)

Comment: Can you please update your question with the current version of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230408/discussion-between-mahela-wickramasekara-and-marcin).